# Tax Calculator not Calculating the Tax

Tags: java

So I am really confused at what I did wrong and I know I made a noobish mistake, but I really need help. If anyone could give me a hint it would be much appreciated. 
I'm working on some code that would calculate income for a single person, but for some reason it is only the credit that comes out.

```
public class TaxReturn 
{
    private double income;
    private double deductions;
    private int numberofExemptions;
    private double credits;
    private double tax;

    public TaxReturn(double salary, double deductable, int exempt,
            double creditable)
    {   
        tax = 0;
        income = salary;
        deductions = deductable;
        numberofExemptions = exempt;
        credits = creditable;
    }

    public void calculateTax()
    {
        final double exempt = 3800;
        double exemption = numberofExemptions * exempt;
        double taxableIncome = income - deductions - exemption;

        final double rate_10 = 0.1;
        final double rate_15 = 0.15;
        final double rate_25 = 0.25;
        final double rate_28 = 0.28;
        final double rate_33 = 0.33;
        final double rate_35 = 0.35;
        final double rate_395 = 0.395;

        final double income1 = 8925;
        final double income2 = 36250;
        final double income3 = 87850;
        final double income4 = 183250;
        final double income5 = 398350;
        final double income6 = 400000;

        while(taxableIncome != 0)
        {
            if(taxableIncome > income6)
            {
                tax = (taxableIncome - income6) * rate_395;
            }
            else if(taxableIncome > income5)
            {
                tax = (taxableIncome - income5) * rate_35;
            }
            else if(taxableIncome > income4)
            {
                tax = (taxableIncome - income4) * rate_33;
            }
            else if(taxableIncome > income3)
            {
                tax = (taxableIncome - income3) * rate_28;
            }
            else if(taxableIncome > income2)
            {
                tax = (taxableIncome - income2) * rate_25;
            }
            else if(taxableIncome > income1)
            {
                tax = (taxableIncome - income1) * rate_15;
            }
            else
            {
                tax = (taxableIncome) * rate_10;
            }
        }
    }

    public int printTaxReturn()
    {
        int amount = (int) ((int)Math.ceil(tax) - credits);
        return amount;
    }
}
```

This is what I use to test the code

```
    public class TaxReturnTester 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        TaxReturn tax = new TaxReturn(80500.5, 20000.00, 3, 5000.00);


        System.out.println(tax.printTaxReturn());
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you call the `TaxReturn` class ?

Comment: Post the invocation context as well. Also you might want to consider using BigDecimal for the calculations rather than double..

Comment: taxableIncome is never modified so your while never ends ..

Comment: You should deduct each tax slab value when tax appied from taxableincome.

Comment: this post is pretty vague. however try to search for Java BigDecimal class. This will help a lot in achieving higher accuracy especially in terms of monetary calculation rather than simply using double.

Comment: I am pretty sure it shouldn't loop forever.  Do you need a loop at all?

Comment: @ArifSamin The OP has values with 6 digits of accuracy and double gives you 15 so I don't think BigDecimal will help.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I've used it for calculating investment rate before and the difference between double and BigDecimal is quite significant. Anyway it's my personal experience. Apologies if it will only makes things harder.

Comment: I am still working on the code and I was just testing it however when I tested the code only the credit was returned and nothing else. I was wondering why it is not calculating the tax or the taxable Income.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to call calculateTax().

You have two options:

Replace TaxReturnTester with this:

```
public class TaxReturnTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TaxReturn tax = new TaxReturn(80500.5, 20000.00, 3, 5000.00);
        tax.calculateTax();
        System.out.println(tax.printTaxReturn());
    }
}
```

OR

Replace your constructor with this:

```
public TaxReturn(double salary, double deductable, int exempt,
            double creditable)
    {   
        tax = 0;
        income = salary;
        deductions = deductable;
        numberofExemptions = exempt;
        credits = creditable;
        calculateTax();
    }
```

I second the fact that you should use BigDecimal in place of floats to calculate money. You will see inconsistencies if not.

It has been recommended by Thihara to use option 1.  If you don't want calculateTax() to be run every time you create the object, you definitely want to go with option 1.

Comment: Thanks it is now calculating the tax but I still have to get it to calculate it correctly.

Comment: I would create a new question with a new title describing your problem.  Feel free to link it here, I will see if I can help.

Comment: Thanks, but I just found out what I did wrong. I was going to respond earlier, computer crashed.

Comment: Please don't use the constructor to call the method. Call it seperately.

Comment: I add it to the printTaxRetrun Method instead because netBeans was telling me that it did not like there. Also changed my code so it is way different from what I had posted.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem basically is that you haven't called the method that does the calculations anywhere.

```
    public class TaxReturnTester 
    {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        TaxReturn tax = new TaxReturn(80500.5, 20000.00, 3, 5000.00);


        tax.calculateTax()

        System.out.println(tax.printTaxReturn());
    }
}
```

I'd recommend against just calling the method from the constructor itself. It's not a very good practice.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it isn't a very good practice.  Not saying you are wrong, just would be a good idea.

Comment: Perhaps I should have worded it to be not good design. Basic reasoning is that a constructor should not do the operations on the object itself that should be done by a client. Calling the method calculateTax should be the responsibility of the client who created and is currently using the particular object. It's fine for a small classroom project etc. But in projects with long lifetimes this kind of things are what contributes to code rot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `while` loop, you can use multiple `if`.

```
if(taxableIncome > income6)
{
    tax = (taxableIncome - income6) * rate_395; taxableIncome -= income6;
}
if(taxableIncome > income5)
{
    tax = (taxableIncome - income5) * rate_35; taxableIncome -= income5;
}
if(taxableIncome > income4)
{
    tax = (taxableIncome - income4) * rate_33; taxableIncome -= income4;
}
if(taxableIncome > income3)
{
    tax = (taxableIncome - income3) * rate_28; taxableIncome -= income3;
}
if(taxableIncome > income2)
{
    tax = (taxableIncome - income2) * rate_25; taxableIncome -= income2
}
if(taxableIncome > income1)
{
    tax = (taxableIncome - income1) * rate_15; taxableIncome -= income1;
}
tax = (taxableIncome) * rate_10;
```